# Configuration to send postfix mail logs to a database

Tags: email, postfix, logging

I have a CentOS 5.5 64 bit mail server using Postfix as the MTA.

I want to create a database of content and the time of mails sent and received from this mail server.  Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean the mail logs or the content of the emails?

Comment: i meant the content of the emails plus the time of mail sent and received.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question lacks detail, and thus my answer will be vague, too. I hope these hints can nudge you to right direction.

One way would be to use `syslog-ng` as your syslog-daemon and configure it in a way it pipes the mail logs to your own script, which then parses the results and inserts them to database. I've written couple of scripts like this in Perl.

Another way would be to use one of the [log summarizers](http://www.postfix.org/addon.html#logfile) available:

Comment: ok i will try this and update you.